# C# Task.Factory.CancellationToken

Tags: c#

My question is about task cancellation. I have to poll the *token.IsCancellationRequested* to detect a cancellation. I call *cts.Cancel();* in a WindowsForm Buttonmethod.

Questions:

1. If I hit the Button is the CancelRequest stored? Or do I have to be lucky, that to same time when I press my Button the code is at the position *if (token.IsCancellationRequested)*?
2. Is it possible to cancel my Task with for-loop by event?

Code Example:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
    // Do syncronius work
    for(int i=0; i<1000;++i)
    {
        DoSyncWork(i);
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
            break;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
   });
```

Comment: For your first point, it sets the IsCancellationRequested to true in the token object so yes it gets stored and the next time your loop hits the if statement it will enter it. I don't quite understand what your second point is asking though

Answer (score 2):

1. The cancellation request is a one time thing. Once a token source is canceled it can never be un-canceled so all derived tokens will have `IsCancellationRequested` always return true.
2. Yes it is possible, but for a `for` loop I don't think it is a better way. The way you use a event is you pass the callback to the [`CancellationToken.Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register(v=vs.110).aspx) method and the callback is your event. I leave it to you how you would make a `Action` delegate cancel the `for` loop.

A few things with your code that you did not bring up:

- [You should never call `Task.Factory.StartNew` without passing in `TaskScheduler`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), if you don't you could cause your code in the `StartNew` to run on the UI thread when you expect it to be on a background thread. Either use `Task.Run` or make sure you pass in a scheduler (`TaskScheduler.Default` is the one `Task.Run(` uses to always run on the background thread, `TaskScheduler.Current` is the one that is used when you don't pass anything in and is the one that can cause stuff to run on the UI thread).
- If you pass the token in to the factory (or to `Task.Run(`) then use [`token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) this will cause the task to enter the `Canceled` state instead of the `Completed` state (if you forget to pass it to the factory it will enter the `Faulted` state), this can be useful for when you need to know when the task finished or not when you are awaiting.

Answer (score 1):

1. The cancellation is "stored". If you call `Cancel()` on your `CancellationTokenSource` instance, the `IsCancellationRequested` property of the `CancellationToken` will be `true` for the rest of its existence.
2. As I understand it, you want to break your `for` loop by an event? I don't know how this should look like. The control flow of a `for` loop is straight forward, no event could break that. But you can use the `token` in the `for` loop's header:

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<1000 && !token.IsCancellationRequested; ++i)
   {
       ...
   }

   // output log if cancelled
   if (token.IsCancellationRequested) Console.WriteLine(...);
   ```

if it's that what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The usual implementation for cancelling out with a cancellation token is to throw the OperationCanceledException, by using the tokens .ThrowIfCancellationRequested. This allows you to catch a cancelled operation and get out of operating for however deep you are in the stack and know that it was cancelled.

For your first question, as soon as the token has been cancelled, cancellation will be requested and when you come back around in the loop the if block would be true that you have. Instead of that though I would just use token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested, and catch the specific OperationCanceledException and do any logging you want.

Second question, you can register a cancellation from anything that can access to your cancellationtokensource by calling cancel. So any event that is able to access the cancellationtokensource you could call it's cancellation event. I will often put a tokensource as an instance variable on a form that should support cancellation so that a "cancel" button or some other event that causes cancellation can call on the cancel method for the cts.

Example of one way I'll set up a form with a token:

```
public class MyForm
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private void Cancel()
    {
        if (_cts != null) {
            _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```